# PHP foreach Group by Value

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to group items within a PHP foreach by their 'field->value' and get the sum of each group separately.  This code below works, but I feel like there is a more efficient way of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<?php

$number_1 = 0;
$number_2 = 0;
$number_3 = 0;

foreach ( $fields as $field ) {   
  if($field->value == 1) {
    $number_1 += $field->number;
  }
  if($field->value == 2) {
    $number_2 += $field->number; 
  }
  if($field->value == 3) {
    $number_3 += $field->number; 
  }
  
}  

echo $number_1; 
echo $number_2; 
echo $number_3; 

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use variable variables.
Generally I would rather recommend an array but it's your choice.

```
foreach ( $fields as $field ) {  
     ${"number_" . $field->value} += $field->number;
}
```

Array version.

```
foreach ( $fields as $field ) {  
     $arr["number_" . $field->value] += $field->number;
}
//  Either output as array or extract values to separate variables.  

Echo $arr["number_1"];
//Or
Extract($arr);
Echo $number_1;
```

Edit had number where it should be value.

Comment: Thanks - this is close, and it actually does get me what I need, but I am now getting a notice: "Notice: Undefined variable" and it references "number_", "number_1", "number_2", "number_3"

Comment: I assumed you would keep the code above the loop. But yes `+=` means you have to first create the variable.

Comment: Is there no way to iterate through creating the variables? It works currently but just trying to understand if there are better ways of doing it  :)  Thanks!

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, I would generally not recommend variables. I would rather use an array.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use separate variables, use an array with `$field->value` as the index.

```
$numbers = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($numbers[$field->value])) {
        $numbers[$field->value] += $field->number;
    } else {
        $numbers[$field->value] = $field->number;
    }
}
```